# greasemonkey is deleting my scripts

Tags: greasemonkey

I have problem with Greasemonkey. Yesterday everything worked, but from this morning, greasemonkey is automatically deleting any script that requires jquery library and using xmlhttpRequest or GM_xmlhttpRequest. What can be problem? I reinstalled plugin, but problem is there...

Comment: Try and work out a recipe that duplicates the problem. ...  I saw this once, myself, just yesterday.  It *may* be a bug when using the "New User Script" menu command and *adding* `@require` directives. I recovered my FF profile from backup and no further problems occurred so far.

Comment: thank you :) it was because of adding require directive when using new user script!

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug that happens in 0.9.14 any time you change any line that defines a downloaded dependency.

https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1502

**Update:** Fixed in release version 0.9.15.

Answer (score 0):

These appear to be known issues in the latest Greasemonkey (0.9.14). Reverting back to 0.9.13 fixed this for now while these bugs are addressed.

Comment: Version 0.9.15 has already been released.  It does not have the problem.